# How to calculate torque to rotate a object resting on four wheels

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Can anyone help with calculation of torque to rotate a circular object which is resting on four wheels.. You can refer attached drawing for better understanding. Out of 4 wheels, two wheels are to provided with drive and other two idler only..if you require any more details please reply..also attached image for better understanding.
[image]
[image]

Comment: `Can anyone help?` is not an engineering question ... please ask about the problem, not about the availability of knowledgeable people

Comment: Several factors including friction, desired rotation rates and imbalance will come into play.

Comment: Steel to steel rolling friction coefficient 0.02

Comment: What is resisting rotation?  If the center of gravity of the circular object is actually in the center (i.e. it stays the same height as the object rotates) then the object itself will not resist rotation at all.   Perhaps there is some resistance to rotation coming from the non-diving rollers?  If you assume this is also zero, then there is no resistance to rotation.